# Java wrapper class subclass of concrete type

Tags: java, subclass, wrapper

Let's say I have a class person as follows:

```
public class Person {
   String name;
   int age;
}
```

and a number of subclasses such as

```
public class Student extends Person {
   // extra fields and methods
}
public class Teacher extends Person {
   // extra fields and methods
}
```

Now, consider that for some application I need to assign an integer id to each person instance, but I don't want to extend the `Person` interface to add the getId() there and a field to hold the id. A simple solution would be to use a wrapper like:

```
public class PersonWrapper extends Person {
    public PersonWrapper(Person p, int id) { // assign the id and other fields }
    public int getId() { return id; }
}
```

This way the client code still works with the Person interface and a wrapped person can be 
treated as a person.
The problem with this approach is that PersonWrapper is a subclass of Person and not Teacher or Student, and such a code won't work:

```
Teacher t = new PersonWrapper(teacher, 1);
t.giveGrade();
```

Of course, it's possible to create concrete wrapper types for all subclasses of `Person`, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution. The ideal solution would be something like this:

```
public class PersonWrapper<T extends Person> extends T
```

so that any PersonWrapper is a subclass of the type it wraps, but it's not possible in Java and I
suspect such definition may not be possible in any language.

In any case, how can I assign ids to subclasses without changing my client code that works with person and its subclasses, without creating a concrete wrapper for each subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that you can't do what you want to do. Assuming that you can't change the concrete classes to be, say, `Student extends Person implements Identifiable`, your best bet is to treat your wrapper really as a wrapper, and have a getter that returns its different elements:

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    private final T item;
    private final int id;

    ...

    public int getId() { return id }

    public T getItem() { return item; }

}
```

This is a *bit* cumbersome to use, because you have to do something like `wrapper.getItem().giveGrade()` instead of just `wrapper.giveGrade()`. It also means you can't shove the wrapper into a `List<Teacher>` and then later downcast it to `TeacherWrapper` -- but that's a bit fragile, and there are often better ways to accomplish what you want. For most cases, this "pure" wrapper approach will do what you want.

Note that I didn't even have `T extends Person`. If the wrapper class doesn't need to use any `Person` methods, there's not much to gain from artificially restrict the generic. The call sites will all have the restriction either way. The *one* difference is that if a call site has a `Wrapper<?>`, then my code will only let you get the item as an `Object`, whereas the more restrictive `T extends Person` will let you get that item as a `Person`.

Answer (score 5):

A wrapper does not necessarily need to extend to the class it's wrapping. So, just use `PersonWrapper<T extends Person>`:

```
public class PersonWrapper<T extends Person> {
    T person;
    int id;

    public PersonWrapper(T person, int id) {
        this.person = person;
        this.id = id;
    }
    //getters and setters...
}
```

Also, a class can only extend from another class at compile time, so it's not possible that this `PersonWrapper` could extend from `Student` and `Teacher` at the same time, which makes *impossible* what you're looking for.

The only solution would be creating proxy classes on the fly using a library like [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib). For example, Spring creates proxies for classes when needs to add functionality on the fly to a class e.g. adding transaction management for methods or whole class.

Comment: But I don't want my client unwrap the person each time it sees it. PersonWrapper is not a subtype of Person!

Comment: @Ali you're contradicting yourself with the first requirement: *consider that for some application I need to assign an integer id to each person instance, but I cannot extend the `Person` interface for that.* Assuming that, your wrapper cannot extend from `PersonWrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

The common solution to this problem is to make `Person` an `interface`.

```
interface Person {

    public String getName();

    public int getAge();
}

class ActualPerson implements Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    ActualPerson(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}

class PersonWithId implements Person {

    private final Person person;
    private final int id;

    PersonWithId(Person person, int id) {
        this.person = person;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return person.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return person.getAge();
    }
}
```

> Do not fear lots of code - the time you take writing code is insignificant compared to the time you spend regretting you didn't do it properly in the first place. *Old Curmudgeon 2014*

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not missing something, but it appears to me that the wrapper pattern solves your problem:

```
public class Person implements IPerson{
    String name;
    int age;

    public  static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Teacher teacherWithID = new Teacher(new PersonWithID(new Person()));
        Teacher teacherWithoutID = new Teacher(new Person());
    }
}

interface IPerson{}

class Teacher implements IPerson{
    public Teacher(IPerson personToBeWrapped){}
}

class Student implements IPerson{
    public Student(IPerson personToBeWrapped){}
}

class PersonWithID implements IPerson{
    public PersonWithID(IPerson personToBeWrapped){}
}
```

Whatever type your variable is should be the last wrapper.

The wrapper pattern can be considered to be a mechanic that allows you to "extend" classes at runtime. It's also called the decorator for that reason. You have competing inheritance mechanics in your code. (the built in one and the pattern) The result is that you cannot type your variable.
If you use the pattern exclusively, it works.